# append data to form a single string using R

Tags: r, string, append, character

I want to form a single string in R:
Below is what data i need to form:

```
list_names <- c("a","b")
answer <- NULL
for (name in list_names){
   append(answer,name)
   append(answer,"\n")
   final <- write.table(df,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
   append(answer,final)
}
print(answer)
```

Output should look like : Single string:

```
a
table1
b 
table2
```

But It seems like it appends only tables not the text. How should I do it? I'm new to R.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `append` method is not altering the value of the `answer` variable. If you want it to you have to do something like: `answer <- append(answer, name)`. Also, the `write.table` method outputs to a file and not a string.

This does what you are looking for:

```
library(stringr)

list_names <- c("a","b")
answer <- ""
for (name in list_names){
  answer <- str_c(answer,name)
  names(df) <- NULL
  final <- str_c(capture.output(print.data.frame(df, row.names = FALSE)) , collapse = "\n")
  answer <- str_c(answer,final, "\n")
}
writeLines(answer)
```

This prints an extra line at the end. You can avoid this if you loop on the list index instead of the names.

Comment: ok as you said that write.table outputs to a file. But here, I'm not actaully saving to a file, I'm simply creating that table in memory,s o what i thought was if I can append this table to a string then it will become a string like in python. Also, you can see in my table line code I have specified col.names=FALSE, sep=",". How do I do this here in your code?

Comment: ok so, I solved my above comment issue using this:final <- str_c(capture.output(write.table(df,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE, sep=",")), collapse = "\n")